# extra line coming in mail body when sending email attachment using apache HTMLEmail

Tags: apache, apache-commons

```
I am using following java code to send email ticket which is Html code in a mail body and also sending same  ticket as attachment a html file. but  some extra lines coming in the body for email clients other than Microsoft outlook like g mail etc,Here is the code,

HtmlEmail service = new HtmlEmail();
//getting body as Html content    
String `strBodyText` = getSpotTicketContent(bobTicketVO,strBhLogoCid);      
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());      
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);   
bw.write(strBodyText);    
bw.close();     
URL filePath = new URL("file:///"+file.getPath());      
service.attach(filePath, ""+orderType+""+dealID+".html""Baydonhill Order Ticket");     
service.send();
```

Every Thing seems to be fine attachment and body coming properly except one extra line coming body such  as ------=_Part_8_20713850.1361775519720--

I am using Apache common emails 1.2 and java 1.4`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

can you describe it more detail?
cause I think the problem is when you read a file with this code :

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());      
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);   
bw.write(strBodyText);    
bw.close();
```

maybe when you read file, some string included when you using that script?
I dont know exactly...